# Why Using 'Await' is not working in 'Async' Function. Functions not waiting to be completed

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, automation

I'm a novice developer and have recently started with Programming.

This is a code to automate the Downloading and then Uploading a file to another website.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong in this code, but the `await` keyword isn't working. The functions are not waiting to be completed before running the next function.

```js
automator = async (MYP_page) => {

    // get all the Data in JSON [function 1]
    vidData = await getData(MYP_page)    

    // download the video [function 2]
    downloadedVideo = await getVid(vidData.MYP_source, vidData.Title);  

    // [function 3]
    console.log("Video Downloaded", "\n", "Now attempting to copy to another Folder")

    // move the video to Local OneDrive Folder [function 4]
    await move2oneDriveLocal(downloadedVideo.absolutePath, "C:/Users/prana/OneDrive/TM media/TM_Vids");  

    // upload the video [function 5]
    // uploadVid(`${vidData.Title}.mp4`)     
    write('P3.csv', fields, vidData);

};
```

All the external functions are async and checked as well.
The `.then` approach doesn't seem to work as well.

Comment: Do these functions return promises?

Comment: Do all the functions, that you are awaiting, return a promise? My initial guess is that not all of them return a promise.

Comment: Declaring a function `async` doesn't necessarily mean it resolves only after its task is finished. Here's an example of buggy code that demonstrates what's most likely the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/tjhuz82f/

Comment: @ChrisG @Yousaf @VLAZ - Thanks for this guys, I really apprecite the input. 
How can I add Promises in my ```async``` function. Is there a website where I can share the project-files with you guys to see.